# I've realized that I had sent/sent you this task before - Past Perfect or Past Simple?

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

Which tense should I use in this sentence and why?

```
I've realized that I had sent/sent you this task before.
```

The context: a couple of days ago my student told me she had sent me some homework that I didn't remember sending her. I checked my email and found out that I indeed had sent it to her. Now I am writing an email to her admitting that.

Comment: I don't see the point of the complex tenses here. Just say *I [now] realize I [already] sent you this task.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you. Your sentence sounds good. :)

Answer (score 1):

What the perfect constructions do in English is to establish or continue some particular temporal focus. "I've realised" set that focus in the present. But *I had sent* sets the focus in the past, and looks back further into the past when I sent the task.

Normally these examples are incompatible;  but there are contexts in which they would make sense together. Your original sentence would then read as

> I've [just now] realized that I had sent you this task before [i.e. before some time in the past which we presumably have already been talking about].

Answer (score 1):

*I realize that I have already sent you this task.* (I realize now.)

or

*I realize that I have sent you this task before.* (I realize now.)

I realized that I had sent you this task before. (I realized in the past.)

We cannot use 'before' with the simple past tense. So 'I sent him before' is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you. I just need to simplify everything. :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to say

> I've realized that I did send you this task

meaning "I now see that I did this thing, even though I thought I hadn't," because

> I've realized that I had sent you this task

implies that you previously knew you sent *a* task, but it was not the correct one and now you are sending a corrected version. That doesn't sound like your situation.

Comment: Randomhead, thank you for your answer. Would it be wrong to say 'I've realized that I sent you this task before' without 'did'? Also, could you, please, specify how the second sentence implies sending correct/not correct tasks?

Comment: @i_yre_b, "I've realized that I sent this before" and "I've realized that I did send this" have the same connotation: "I thought I had not done this, but in reality I did." That said I probably would not use the "before" sentence, it doesn't sound exactly right to my ear. Saying "I've realized I had sent this" is *pluperfect* and implies that you did the sending before some *other* past event happened, which is not what I gather from your context. That's why I said it sounded like it was in the context of a newly-corrected task, for example.

Comment: Randomhead, thank you for the explanation. The first one is clear, but the second one is still confusing. Probably, Present Perfect and Past Perfect just don't work together, do they? We use Past Perfect to refer to an action happened before the time in the past we are describing, but if Present Perfect is a present tense, I suppose, it doesn't really refer to a past action. Am I right?

Comment: @i_yre_b I don't have a good definitive answer offhand, I'm sorry. I will just say again that to my ear "I did send this" emphasizes the fact that *something was sent* while "I had sent this" emphasizes the fact that *this* thing was sent rather than *some other thing*.

Comment: It's something new for me really. I've never thought of it his way. I considered using Past Perfect because I thought that 'sending' happened before 'realizing'. However, as realizing has happened just now, I used Present Perfect, which makes it complicated. I guess as I'm discussing this question with you, I'm realizing that Past Simple is kind of 'one step back' from Present Perfect, which makes the use of Past Perfect wrong.